# multiple data insert into database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i am new to laravel i am having trouble in inserting data into database and throwing error as

> "count(): Parameter must be an 
>        array or an object that implements Countable"

i want to add attendence details of all the registred employees in the databse

controller

```
    public function Attendence() 
    {
        $data=employee_data::all();
        return view('attendence',compact('data'));
    }   

    public function mark_attendence(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
        'date'  =>  'required',
        'is_present'  =>  'required'

        ]);


        $data=$request->all();
        $last_id=employee_data::create($data)->id;
        if (count($request->is_present) >0 )
         {
            # code...
            foreach ($return->is_present as $item => $v)
            {
                $data2=array(
                    'is_present' =>$request->is_present[$item],
                    'date'=> $request->date[$item],
                    'user_id'=>$last_id
                );

            }
        //$data2->save();

    //$employee->save();
    //$employee->employee_data()->create([]);



        return redirect('/index')->with('succ','Attendence Added Successfully');
    }
```

Blade output:

[image]

Submit

    
        
            Id
            First Name
            Last Name
            DateOfJoining
            post
            Remark
        
        @foreach( $data as $row )
            
                {{ $row->id }}
                {{ $row->first_name }}
                {{ $row->last_name }}
                {{ $row->date_joining }}
                {{ $row->post }}

                
                    
                            Present 
                    

                    
                             Absent
                    

            
        @endforeach
        
            Id
            First Name
            Last Name
            DateOfJoining
            post
            Remark

Model
class employee_attendence extends Model
{
    //

```
protected $fillable  = array('is_present' ,'date', 'user_id' );
//protected $fillable=[];
public $timemstamps= false ;

public function employee_data(){
        //return $this->hasOne(employee_data::class,'App/employee_data');
    return $this->hasOne('App\employee_data');

}
```

}

Model2

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class employee_data extends Model
{
    //protected $fillabel=['first_name','last_name','contact_no','date_joining','post'];

```
protected $fillable  = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'contact_no' ,'date_joining','post' );
//protected $fillable=[];
public $timemstamps= false ;

public function employee_attendence()
{
        //return $this->hasOne( employee_attendence::class, 'App/employee_attendence');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\employee_attendence');
}
```

}

Comment: Is your `is_present` an array from the view side ?

Comment: no 
<input type="date" value="CURDATE()" name="date[]" style="text-align: left;float: inline-end; margin-left: 850px;"  >

<td>
     <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Present" name="is_present[]" value="Present">&nbsp &nbsp Present 
         </label>
          
       <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Absent" name="is_present[]" value="Absent">&nbsp &nbsp Absent
          </label></td>

Comment: See my below answer it will work for you. But you have values like `Absent` and `Present` So check the conditions accordingly.

Comment: its throwing an error:undefined error :return

Comment: Are you marking absent or present each at a time or first you check or uncheck then submit it at once ?

Comment: first i check whether present or absent and then submit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213609/discussion-between-akhtar-munir-and-shruti-menkudle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understand. You might have `is_present` will be an array format from view like `name="is_present[]"`. If this your case then the below code will work fine. if not then you can't use `count()` if input is not an object or array

```
public function mark_attendence(Request $request)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($request->is_present); $i++)
    {
        $emp = new employee_attendence();

        if($request->is_present[$i] == "Present")
        $emp->is_present = "Present";
        if($request->is_present[$i] == "Absent")
        $emp->is_present = "Absent";

        $emp->date = now();
        $emp->user_id = $request->user_id[$i];
        $emp->save();
    }
    return redirect('/index')->with('succ','Attendence Added Successfully');
}
```

Comment: ErrorException
Undefined variable: return

Comment: I have just showed a simple logic for the loop. You have to insert `$data2` into a table below.

Comment: $data2 ? into the table

Answer (score 1):

In your Add Attendance method try this 
this worked for me

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($request->is_present); $i++)
    {
        $emp = new employee_attendence();

        if($request->is_present[$i] == "Present")
            $emp->is_present = "Present";
        if($request->is_present[$i] == "Absent")
            $emp->is_present = "Absent";

            $emp->date = $request->date; 
            $emp->user_id = $request->user_id[$i];
            $emp->save();
    }
```

Comment: If you remember I gave you that answer too.